# Monitoring disease activity or monitoring of disease activity

Tags: prepositions

Please let me know which of the following sentences is correct:

"*In daily clinical practice, patient-reported outcome measures are used as guidance for initiating tumor necrosis factor inhibitors (TNFis) and **monitoring of disease activity** once treatment is initiated*."

Or

"*In daily clinical practice, patient-reported outcome measures are used as guidance for initiating tumor necrosis factor inhibitors (TNFis) and **monitoring disease activity** once treatment is initiated.*"

To me option 1 sounds better, but Grammarly keeps insisting that option 2 is better. Would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Did you mean to leave out _are_ in the second version? In any case, I agree that Option 1 sounds better. Grammar checkers aren't infallible.

Comment: @KateBunting No, I did not mean to leave out "are". The question has been edited. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I would have gone for option 2 since it mirrors the structure of initiating TNF